# Displaying table in PDF using ITextSharp and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, itext

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 environment.  I am already able to view the PDF using iText5 for .NET. However, there are many columns in my original grid and I am just listing them in the PDF so a better approach would be to display it in a table.

I've constructed something like this in my controller which will populate my PdfPTable with the data I need:

```
Enroll.dTable = new PdfPTable(2);
Enroll.dTable.AddCell(itemType3.Name);
Enroll.dTable.AddCell(itemType3.Code);
```

However, I don't know how to display the PDFTable in my View. I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
@if (Model.dTable != null)
{
    <chunk size ="10.0"> @Model.dTable</chunk>
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that this way. Produced PDF is a binary file and you need to flush it to the browser using "FileContentResult". So create the PDF file somewhere else out of your controller and then "return File" in your "FileContentResult" method in the controller.